# Proving two equations involving the greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show or prove that $$\gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1} ,a + 1\right )=\gcd(a + 1 , 2m),$$
>   and that
>   $$\gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m + 1}+1}{a+1} , a + 1\right)=\gcd(a + 1 , 2m + 1).$$

Comment: I have an example!

Comment: ((a^(m)-1)/(a-1),a-1)=(a-1,m)

d = (a^(m−1) + a^(m−2) + • • • + a + 1, a − 1)=

(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1) + m, a – 1

we know that

a − 1|(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1)

(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1) = n(a − 1)

Soon

d = (n(a − 1) + m, a − 1) = (a − 1, n(a − 1) + m) = (a − 1, m)

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Try to invest some time into making it readable. (This site supports LaTeX, which makes mathematical formulas much easier to read.) Also consider editing your question to add your own work to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let integer $d\ne0$ divides $a+1$ i.e., $a+1=c\cdot d$(say)  where $c\ne0$ is some integer

$\implies a=c\cdot d-1$

$$\gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1} ,a + 1\right )$$
$$=\gcd \left(\frac{(c\cdot d-1)^{2m}-1}{c\cdot d} ,c\cdot d\right )$$
$$=\gcd \left( (c\cdot d)^{2m-1}-\binom{2m}1(c\cdot d)^{2m-2}+ \binom{2m}2(c\cdot d)^{2m-3}+\cdots+\binom{2m}{2m-2}(c\cdot d)-\binom{2m}{2m-1},c\cdot d\right)$$

$$=\gcd\left( c\cdot d\{(c\cdot d)^{2m-2}-\binom{2m}1(c\cdot d)^{2m-3}+ \binom{2m}2(c\cdot d)^{2m-4}+\cdots+\binom{2m}{2m-2}\}-2m,c\cdot d\right)\text{ as } \binom{2m}{2m-1}=\binom{2m}{2m-(2m-1)}=\binom{2m}1=2m$$

$$=\gcd(-2m, c\cdot d)\text{ as }\gcd(p+kq,q)=\gcd(p,q)$$

$$=\gcd(2m, a+1)$$

Can you solve the second one now?

Comment: ((a^(m)-1)/(a-1),a-1)=(a-1,m)

d = (a^(m−1) + a^(m−2) + • • • + a + 1, a − 1)=

(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1) + m, a – 1

we know that

a − 1|(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1)

(a^(m−1) − 1) + (a^(m−2) − 1) + • • • + (a − 1) = n(a − 1)

Soon

d = (n(a − 1) + m, a − 1) = (a − 1, n(a − 1) + m) = (a − 1, m)

Comment: @user77961, that's what I did , may be in a different way

Comment: Your answer is very good, but I think for the level I'm can not understand well ...
Not yet know these figures in parentheses are one above the other.
I'm sorry.

Comment: @user77961, do you know Binomial Theorem?

Comment: Yes I know.
This number then, are the binomial coefficients?

Comment: Sou Brasileiro, não consigo ir bem com o inglês, desculpe qualquer incoerencia!

Answer (score 3):

I will show that $$\gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1} ,a + 1\right )=\gcd(a + 1 , 2m)$$

First note that $$a^{2m}-1=(a^2)^m-1=(a^2-1)(a^{2(m-1)}+
a^{2(m-2)}+\cdots+1)$$

so that $$\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}=(a-1)(a^{2(m-1)}+\cdots+1)$$

But $a\equiv -1 \mod a+1$ so we have

$$\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}\equiv -2((-1)^{2(m-1)}+\cdots+1)=-2m$$

which means $$\gcd \left(\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1} ,a + 1\right )=\gcd(a + 1 , 2m)$$
Can you do something similar with the other?

Comment: Is to make this statement without using mod?
More or less as in the example of the issue:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392745/theory-number-gcd

Comment: @user77961 Could you rephrase?