# Prove $\gcd\left((a^{2m}−1)/(a+1),a+1\right)=\gcd(a+1,2m)$

Tags: number-theory

Show or prove that
$$
\gcd\left(\frac{a^{2m}−1}{a+1},a+1\right)=\gcd(a+1,2m),
$$
and that
$$
\gcd\left(\frac{a^{2m+1}+1}{a+1},a+1\right)=\gcd(a+1,2m+1).
$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392649/proving-two-equations-involving-the-greatest-common-divisor

Comment: @Stahl, the edit is not correct, please find the above link

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, I just realized that those numbers wouldn't be integers in general, although it seemed to be what the original question was asking. *edited*

Comment: @user77961: you just asked this in another question. Please don't spam the front page with the same question, especially if you are not putting any effort into finding the solution yourself (or at least showing us your thoughts).

Comment: I'm new to the site, I created the account on the site today.
Excuse me.
You need to learn it fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{a^{2m}-1}{a+1}=\frac{a^2-1}{a+1}(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+...a^2+1)$$
$$=(a+1)(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+...a^2+1)-2(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+...a^2+1)$$
$$=(a+1)(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+...a^2+1)-2(a^{2m-2}-1+a^{2m-4}-1+...a^2-1+2m)$$
$$=(a+1)(a^{2m-2}+a^{2m-4}+...a^2+1)-2[(a^{2m-2}-1)+(a^{2m-4}-1)+...(a^2-1)]+2m$$

**Hint 2** Each of $(a^{2m-2}-1),(a^{2m-4}-1),...,(a^2-1)$ is divisible by $a+1$.